# Where do I place the "links" in a .vue file?

Tags: vue.js

Where do I place links like these:

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">"
```

It gives me error if I just place them in the beginning or end of a .vue file, and it would be redundant, cause I need them available for all the project

Answer (score 1):

.vue single file component format [doesn't allow for arbitrary tags](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#language-blocks). If there's a need for `<link>` and its [type is suitable for `<body>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok), it can be placed into `<template>` block. Stylesheets [can be provided as `<style>` blocks](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#style) and don't need `<link>`. `<link rel="icon">` isn't body-ok and needs to be placed in `<head>`, so it's not suitable for a component that was placed in `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the Vue-CLI place external links and scripts on the `<head>` Tag in the `index.html` file. You can find this under the `public` folder.

Otherwise if you want to import an external file to a component you can do it like:

```
<style src="/.styleone.css"></style>
<style src="./styletwo.css"></style>
<style src="./stylethree.css"></style>
```